# connecting multiple lans with openvpns iroute directive

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, amazon-vpc, site-to-site-vpn

I have multiple AWS VPC network and want to connect in the following configuration using OpenVPN

```
+---------+             +---------+
| vpc1    |             | vpc2    |
+---------+             +---------+
           \           /
            +---------+
            | vpc0    |
            +---------+
                 |
            +---------+
            | local   |
            +---------+
```

and below is details about each VPC

```
+--------------------------+
| VPC  | subnet  | region  |
+------+---------+---------+
| vpc0 | 10.0/16 | region0 |
| vpc1 | 10.1/16 | region1 |
| vpc2 | 10.2/16 | region0 |
+------+---------+---------+
```

I am able to connect to all the instance in `vpc0` using simple OpenVPN configuration and `vpc2` being in the same region I was able to do VPC peering with `vpc0` and connect to instances in `vpc2`. Although I am not able to access instances in `vpc1`.

My OpenVPNs `server.conf` in `vpc0` looks like this

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir ccd
mode server
topology subnet
tls-server

push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0"
push "route 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0"
push "route 10.2.0.0 255.255.0.0"
route 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0

keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0
```

client configuration for `vpc1` in `/etc/openvpn/ccd`

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0"
iroute 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

route table in `vpc0`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.240.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.1.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.0.0     UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
```

For connecting from `vpc1` I created a client certificate as `vpc1.ovpn` and then just started a process in `vpc1` machine as `openvpn --config vpc1.ovpn`. After starting this process I am able to reach any machine in `vpc0` and `vpc2` from `vpc1` but I am not able to reach to `vpc1` instances from `vpc0` machine or any instance. The route table on `vpc1` machine is.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         10.1.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.0.0        10.8.0.1        255.255.0.0     UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.1.0.0        *               255.255.240.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.2.0.0        10.8.0.1        255.255.0.0     UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
```

P.S. I had followed [this](http://backreference.org/2009/11/15/openvpn-and-iroute/) for setup.

Comment: There was a small mistake at my end the file name in `ccd/` should be same as the `client name`, client name can be also found in `openvpn-status.log` once client connects. The second mistake was `ifconfig-push 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0` in config_file should have been `ifconfig-push 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0`

Comment: Do you have the routes setup and a peer with VPC 1? Check the routes in vpc 1 to vpc 0 and vice versa in vpc 0 to 1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/peering-configurations-full-access.html#one-to-many-vpcs-full-access

Comment: Also this might help https://aws.amazon.com/articles/connecting-multiple-vpcs-with-ec2-instances-ipsec/

Comment: Depends on the regions as well, Inter-Region VPC Peering is available in AWS US East (N. Virginia), US East (Ohio), US West (Oregon) and EU (Ireland) with support for other regions coming soon. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/announcing-support-for-inter-region-vpc-peering/

Comment: @strongjz 
1. yeah routes where setup.
2. that is a bit ugly as you need to have a different server for each VPC and each instance runs on a different port.
3. I am aware of that. As mentioned I had an issue connecting two OpenVPN vpcs.